# compiling error while calling a function from macro

Tags: c++, function, macros, g++, ostream

We have a MACRO {TT(msg)}, and inside that macro, we are calling a function with the same argument which we received in the macro i.e. 'msg'. the function which is called from the macro is expecting a string argument. Now assume if the macro is called like **TT("argument")** then the program is compiling and working as expected, but if we will call the macro like **TT("argument"<<i)** then it is giving below compilation error.

**main.cpp:14:14: error: invalid operands of types ‘const char [4]’ and ‘int’ to binary ‘operator<<’**

Reason for the issue: when the TT() macro will be called it will directly call the func() API with parameter since the msg is having some other values **"XYZ" << i** which can’t be handled by the func(). so somehow we need to handle this.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
#define TT(msg) func(msg);

void func (string msg) {
    cout << msg;
    
}

int main()
{   
    int i=9;
    TT ("XYZ"<<i);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To answer the question as asked... It's a bad idea in my opinion, but it is *possible* (see at the bottom of the answer for how):

Why do I think you shouldn't introduce that syntax?

When looking at `TT ("XYZ"<<i);`, it gives the impression that the result of the `"XYZ"<<i` expression is passed to `TT()`. i.e. One would expect the following to work, but they can't. That's just plain *misleading*:

```cpp
auto tmp = "XYZ" << i;  // Nope, can't do this
TT (tmp);

TT (("XYZ" << i)); // Doesn't work either.
```

I'd suggest the following instead:

```cpp
using namespace std;
#define TT(msg) func(msg);

std::ostream& func(string msg) {
    cout << msg;
    return cout;
}

int main()
{   
    int i=9;
    TT ("XYZ") << i;

    // or just call func() directly. TT() doesn't serve any purpose:
    func("XYZ") << i;
    return 0;
}
```

It's effectively the same syntax, and it doesn't lead to any confusion. On top of that, it doesn't suffer from having to build an intermediate string.

If you have no choice but to implement the syntax you posted, here's how you can do it:

"Copy-Paste" the entire message expression as the right-hand side of an `std::ostringstream`'s `operator<<()`. Wrapping the whole thing in an immediately invoked lambda;

```cpp
#include <sstream>
#define TT(msg_expr) func([&] {                            \
    std::ostringstream tmp_stream_avoid_name_collisions{}; \
    tmp_stream_avoid_name_collisions << msg_expr;          \
    return tmp_stream_avoid_name_collisions.str();         \
}());
```

Comment: Getting this err:       main.cpp:12:62: error: ‘class std::basic_ostream’ has no member named ‘str’; did you mean ‘setf’?
 #define TT(msg_expr) func((std::ostringstream{} << msg_expr).str());

Comment: That's because the version I landed on does not play well with the way `operator<<()` is commonly  overloaded. I've reverted the answer back to my original, much uglier, but evidently better implementation.